# Can I call a batch file from a TFS build?

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to create a TFS build that simply calls a batch file (does not build a project or solution)?

All the examples I'm seeing call a solution or project.

Comment: Which build are you using? XAML or vNext build?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT XAML

Answer (score 1):

For **vNext** build in TFS, it's task based. You could simply add a batch script task in your build definition. No need to build any solution or project.

[image]

For **XAML** build you could also ignore build a project or solution, but it's a litter complicated. You need to customize your build process template, after that only have to select a `.bat` file in the process.

[image]

More detail steps about how to do this please refer this tutorial: [Run batch file from TFS build](https://vlukashevych.wordpress.com/2015/02/01/run-batch-file-from-tfs-build/)

Comment: I had seen that tutorial before but he glosses over the process of modifying a template.  I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @JoelFan It's easy to do this. And if you stay on XAML build, which is also a very useful feature. You could follow the official step-by-step tutorial: [Customize your build process template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647551(v=vs.120).aspx) & a more detail tutorial blog: http://blogs.objectsharp.com/post/2012/03/01/Editing-a-Build-Process.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you're not keen on editing the build template, another option might be to use the stock XAML build template, create a dummy.proj file that gets "built," and use the pre- or post-build scripts. You can invoke the batch file from a simple PowerShell script. Here's what the dummy.proj would look like:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Default">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TPath>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\ExtensionPack\4.0\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks</TPath>
    <TPath Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\ExtensionPack\4.0\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks')">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\ExtensionPack\4.0\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks</TPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(TPath)"/>

    <Target Name="Default">
      <Message Text="Hello, world." />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: How do I add a post-build script?

Comment: It's in the "Advanced" sub-section of the Build section. Have your script located in source control, then use the source path to that script:
$/MyProject/MyPowerShellScript.ps1

Comment: So I open the .proj file in Visual Studio?

Comment: Not exactly, no - you do need to create the dummy.proj file, but it is the Project target in the build definition. It's in the "Build" section,  "1. Projects" sub-section. That satisfies the build definition's need to build something, then you use the post-build script to run your batch file.